# if the limit value is always indeterminate?

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

Does it mean anything if the function limit is 0/0 after performing some algebraic manipulation? it still is indeterminate, right? and would i determine such by just graphing it or ?

Comment: Have you applied L'Hopitals Rule? Or can you apply it I should ask

Comment: It'd be more helpful if you gave us the specific example.  The basic answer though is that the limit is still indeterminate, so more manipulation is required.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin no i can't because i haven't known about it yet.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom really sorry as i do not recall and i don't have the problem with me i just saw one.

Comment: Then Omnomnomnom has given you the most appropriate answer, though graphing the function of which you are trying to take a limit may help you gain an intuition as to what the limit is or may be.  But, again, without knowing the function you're asking about, there is no way we can help you beyond the comments given.

Comment: Oh,
ok i get it .
thanks. :)

Comment: Mohamed - Take a look at the [Wikipedia entry on Indeterminate Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).  You might find some inspiration there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test if a limit actually exists by computing one-sided limits.
Example :

$\lim _{x\to 0^{+}}{1 \over 1+2^{-1/x}}=1$

${\lim _{x\to 0^{-}}{1 \over 1+2^{-1/x}}=0}$

If upper and lower bound are not equal then it simply doesn't exist.

Comment: You are right @amWhy , but Mohamed didn't actually give the function.Regardless of what the function is calculating the one-sided limits will give him a clear answer if he actually needs to make more manipulations.